# Codemirror not working with Yii view, bootstrap

Tags: php, yii, codemirror

I am trying to integrate Codemirror to one of my view in Yii 1

but the result is not good.

Please help me.

In Controller: I registered

```
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/codemirror.js', \CClientScript::POS_BEGIN);
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/php.js', \CClientScript::POS_BEGIN);
```

In view.php

```
    <textarea id="editor" name="editor" rows="10" style="width: inherit;">
    <?= htmlentities($model->diff_content); ?>
</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var e = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
        mode: "application/x-httpd-php"
        //theme: 'blackboard'
    });
    /*function app() {

        var txt = "myText";
        $('textarea#code').text(txt);
    }*/
</script>
```

Result:
[image]

thank you very much

Comment: you should not be doing that in a controller

Comment: why? I can see the script are added in the top of the html page

Comment: adding scripts in controller is not a good practice.

Comment: But it does not help

Comment: do you get any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question

```
$cs->registerCssFile($baseUrl.'/css/codemirror.css', \CClientScript::POS_BEGIN);
```

It will generate

and this is the problem

I have to change to

```
$cs->registerCssFile($baseUrl.'/css/codemirror.css');
```

without \CClientScript::POS_BEGIN

Everything back to work.